# Adding RPC node in private network without node authorization

Tags: rpc, network

I have set up a private network and it has node_authorization pallet included. I have added several validator nodes by using the node_authorization pallet as well_known nodes.

Now I want to allow some users to set up an RPC node(Readable nodes to hold all blockchain data) for their dApps and it does not require any sort of authorization (sudo access).